# Preferred way of adding spinner to toolbar

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner, android-toolbar

I want to add a `spinner` to my `toolbar`. When researching I found a lot of different ways on how to do this, however the newest were about 4 years old and the solutions I found did not feature kotlin. Since kotlin is the "standard" nowadays I am wondering, what is the preferred way of doing this today? Or is there even a preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything much has changed in 4 years - the Material version of a Spinner is an [Exposed Dropdown Menu](https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu) which seems to be "pretend a `TextView` works like an `Adapter`" and is a real pain if you just want to know item 2 was selected or whatever. All having to implement "text changed" callbacks and look at what the text is now, what does that correspond to, etc

Have you looked at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)? That's pretty much all there is to it, I don't think you need to do anything special so long as you're [adding your own `Toolbar` to layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/) instead of using the old system one. It's just another view in your layout.

Kotlin doesn't seem to bring anything new to it, apart from the syntax being a bit nicer for some things. You still have to implement a two-method callback interface for the `Adapter` so you can't use a nice simple lambda or anything